# Thowing localized system_error on Win32

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

This is a question I'm gonna answer myself. I don't know if my solution is perfect but others may have some ideas about that.
If I throw a system_error with system_category() the translation of the error code into a string by system_category() (it returns a polymoprhic error_category) isn't localized acording to the current thread's locale under Windows. I mentioned this on the VC++ support forum and someone from MS responded that this is a limitation which will be fixed in the next release except from WInRT-code.
So I needed a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>

struct xsystem_category : public std::error_category
{
    xsystem_category() = default;
    xsystem_category( xsystem_category const & ) = delete;
    virtual ~xsystem_category() override = default;
    void operator =( xsystem_category const & ) = delete;
    virtual char const *name() const noexcept override;
    virtual std::error_condition default_error_condition( int code ) const noexcept override;
    virtual bool equivalent( int code, std::error_condition const &condition ) const noexcept override;
    virtual bool equivalent( std::error_code const &code, int condition ) const noexcept override;
    virtual std::string message( int condition ) const override;
};

char const *xsystem_category::name() const noexcept
{
    return "xsystem_category";
}

std::error_condition xsystem_category::default_error_condition( int code ) const noexcept
{
    return std::error_condition( code, xsystem_category() );
}

inline bool xsystem_category::equivalent( int code, std::error_condition const &condition ) const noexcept
{
    return default_error_condition( code ) == condition;
}

inline bool xsystem_category::equivalent( std::error_code const &code, int condition ) const noexcept
{
    return *this == code.category() && code.value() == condition;
}

std::string xsystem_category::message( int condition ) const
{
    using namespace std;
    LCID lcid = GetThreadLocale();
    string errStr( 64, '\0' );
    while( !FormatMessageA( FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, nullptr, condition, lcid, errStr.data(), (DWORD)errStr.size(), nullptr ) )
        if( DWORD dwFmErr = GetLastError(); dwFmErr == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER )
            errStr.resize( 2 * errStr.size(), '\0' );
        else
            throw system_error( (int)dwFmErr, system_category(), "localized FormatMessage() for xsystem_category::message() failed" );
    errStr.resize( strlen( errStr.data() ) );
    return errStr;
}
```

Maybe there's someone which suggests some improvements here.

Comment: You've already [received feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73413376/own-kind-of-system-error-for-win32#comment129646102_73413376). Why did you ignore it? This all looks like another request for a code review in disguise.

Comment: I was requested to do a question which I ask myself. I woudln't be the only one that profits from some improvemets, but also others.

Comment: I don't get it. You already **know** that the code is wrong. You even got a test case to verify how it fails (use the error code `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`, for example). You also know how to fix that part, but you didn't care to do so. Sorry, if you're looking for a code review here, you'll get votes instead.

Comment: From where should I know that ?

Comment: I posted a [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071128-00/?p=24353) that explains this. Anyway, those error messages aren't intended to be user-facing, and having them localized isn't just not useful. It's actively harmful.

Comment: If those messages wouldn't be intended for the user there won't be any .what().

Comment: `what()` is for *diagnostics*, not UI. And you absolutely, positively want your logs to use a fixed, deterministic language. Nothing worse than failing to find a particular string in French only to realize hours later that the specific log entry was written from a thread, that, for some reason, had its locale changed to Italian.

Comment: That's an opinion, not a fact.

Comment: Error messages do not gracefully cross domain boundaries. The domain of the system error codes is code construction. Those errors are useful to the author of a piece of software. When you move to the UI you're crossing a boundary. The domain now is the use of a program. There's not much a user can do with an `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error other than ignore it, localized or not. Localizing those error messages only instigates use of those messages in a domain where they provide no value. Feel free to subscribe that to opinion.

Comment: That's an opinion, not a fact. Most errors are descriptive and it's common to present them to the user. There's nothing in the documentation of FormatMessage() or .what() that say's that this is only for diagnostic purposes. If you judge reality according to your motivational situation, you make mistakes. I addressed the whole thing in the Microsoft developer forum and someone from Microsoft said that it would be fixed, except for WinRT apps. I think they know better than you.

Comment: So then, moving back to facts: There's still at least one bug in the code that hasn't been fixed. Also, please provide a link to the Dev Community discussion, so that others can provide feedback.

Comment: I won't give you that link because I'm afraid you publish your opininions there also.

Comment: It's only opinion, what are you actually afraid of? That those opinions may hold more merit than you'd be willing to accept?

Comment: That's a discussion that doesn't make sense. Things are simply not defined the way you prefer.

Comment: Post the link and we'll find out.

Comment: I won't give that link because I'm sure you would continue your personal mission there. And there's no need for further debates like that since the technical discussion has been finished. I'd like have read something about the other methods of xsystem_category but you won't have helped here.